# What synthesizer should I get if I like vintage sound e.g. Roland Juno 60?

Tags: midi, synthesizer, analog

I like a warm, dry sound like Roland Juno 60 but the vintage Juno are not multitimbral. Is there a modern synthesizer, perhaps digital but preferably analogue, that has the warm sound of Roland Juno 60 and also is multitimbral? I used to own a Roland Juno 60 and play it with the DCB converter but I gave it away to a friend and now I want another synthesizer.

### Update

I've gotten a Roland Juno 106 for SEK 5500 (abt 820 USD) and I'm happy with it even though it's not multitimbral.

Comment: It depends on your DAW

Comment: A truely multitimbral analogue synthesizer necessarily has to be basically two (or _n_) complete synthesizers in a box. So it's often more practical to actually use two separate synths; gives you in many ways more control. Or, of course, go digital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you care more about the synth or the sound?

If it is all about the sound, then get yourself a copy of [Native Instruments Kontakt](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/synths-samplers/kontakt-5/) and borrow your Juno back to record some patches. Then have fun in Kontakt. Another option would be to buy one of the smaller Moogs and sample that. Sure, it is monophonic, but you only need to record one note at a time into your sampler.

If it is about the tactile interface of the Juno, then you need to find another hardware synth. From a user interface perspective, the [Novation Supernova II Keyboard](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/dec00/articles/novation.asp) is, by far, my favorite. Unfortunately, they are hard to find, have power supply issues, and can sound a bit digital at times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yesterday I bought a Roland Juno 106 for abt 820 USD in Västerås outside Stockholm, Sweden and I've connected it and I'm happy now.

Comment: How are you going to overcome the lack of multitimbrality?

Comment: Thank you for the question. I'm going to buy a Nord Modular tomorrow which is multitimbral but difficult to use. They are constructed in Stockholm so I can get one easily and still have the voices from the Juno, and/or get another Juno plus the advice I'm getting here.

Comment: If you can, grab a G2. The additional sequencing and FX stuff that the G2 can do is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many modern synthesizers that have older-style tones and voices built in.

I think I have seen Juno voices on a couple of the more recent Rolands. Not sure if they are multi-timbral or accurate reconstructions though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to go the VST route, there are a couple emulators out there. [TAL-U-NO-LX](http://kunz.corrupt.ch/products/tal-u-no-lx) comes to mind.

VST emulators (arguably) usually do a decent job of sounding very close to the actual hardware, but they require a computer and usually a host to run them.